# Is there a simple way to host a program with a small data file (esp. on Heroku)?

Tags: database, heroku, yaml

If you [go to](http://simple-to-do.herokuapp.com) my Heroku-hosted [to do list program](https://github.com/SangerGroup/todo), you can put test data in, but it's gone pretty soon. This is because, I learned, Heroku has an "ephemeral" filesystem and disposes of any data that users write to it via `post`. I don't know how to set up a PostgreSQL database or any other kind of database (although maybe I soon will, as I'm working through Hartl's Rails tutorial). I'm just using a humble YAML file. It works fine in my local environment.

Any suggestions for beginners to work around this problem, short of just learning how to host a database? Is there another free service I might use that would work without further setup? Any advice greatly welcome.

I fully understand that I can't do what I'm trying to do with Heroku (see e.g. [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518640/heroku-delete-my-uploaded-files-why?rq=1)). I just want to understand my options better.

UPDATE: Looks like [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-dropbox-ruby-rails-heroku-serjik-isagholian) and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/ruby) might have some ideas about using Dropbox to host (read/write) flat files.

Comment: If you REALLY hate databases, you can go the Redis route. Redis is an in-memory Key-Value data store. Heroku provides excellent hosting for Redis.

Comment: Redis sounds like Yaml in that it's also a key-value data store. But if it's an in-memory database, doesn't that mean the data is, I don't know, more at risk in case there's a server restart or something?

And it's not that I hate 'em, it's just that I don't understand 'em!

Comment: Yes, that's always an issue. However, if you're worried about that, you could have it back up into a file every 5 minutes or so to a dropbox account.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask to have Heroku, you know, *read from* a Dropbox file??

Comment: You know, this has got me thinking. Isn't it possible to have Ruby write and read directly to and from an external file hosted on Dropbox? Maybe supply the Dropbox file address in an environmental variable on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. But I'll take a minute to explain why.

I realize that you aren't yet familiar with building web applications, databases, and all that stuff. And that's OK! This is an excellent question.

What you need to know, however, is that doing what you're asking is a really bad idea when you're trying to build scalable websites. And Heroku is a platform company that SPECIFICALLY tries to help developers building scalable websites. That's really what the platform excels at.

While Heroku is really easy to learn and use, it isn't targeted at beginners. It's meant for experienced developers. This is really clear if you take a look at what Heroku's principles are, and what policies they enforce on their platform.

Heroku goes out of their way to make building scalable websites really easy, and makes it VERY difficult to do things that would make building scalable websites harder.

So, let's talk for a second about why Heroku has an ephemeral file system in the first place!

This design decision forces you (the developer of the application) to store files that your application needs in a safer, faster, dedicated file storage service (like Amazon S3). This practice results in a lot of scalability benefits:

- If your webservers don't need to write to disk, they can be deployed many many times without worrying about storage constraints.
- No disks need to be shared across webservers. Sharing disks typically causes IO contention and can adversely affect performance.
- It makes it easy to scale your web application horizontally across commodity servers, since disk resources aren't required.

So, the reason why you cannot store flat files on Heroku is because doing this causes scalability and performance problems, and would make it nearly impossible for Heroku to help you scale your application easily (which is their main goal).

That is why it is recommended to use a file storage service to store files (like Amazon S3), or a database for storing data (like Postgres).

What I'd recommend doing (personally) is using [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql). You mentioned you're using rails, and rails has excellent Postgres support built in. It has what's called an ORM that let's you talk to the database using some very simple Ruby objects, and removes almost all the prerequisite database background to get things going. It's really fun / easy once you give it a try!

Finally: Heroku Postgres also has a great free plan, which means you can store the data for your todo app in it for no cost at all.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This definitely helps. Although I'm not trying to build a scaleable website. I don't have time for that shit. I'd just like to have a little website that I and a few friends use, by way of a beginning learning project. I am under no illusions that my pitiful little website will *need* to scale. :-)

Comment: In that case, I'd like to highly recommend using something like DigitalOcean. Or even Amazon LightSail. These are small VPS providers that give you a small linux server for a very small cost per month, on which you can copy over your code, run your app, and do whatever you want with =) For situations like what you're trying to do, this is your best bet!